# Understanding Python references

Tags: python

Given that everything in python is by reference, I do understand what's happening in the code below:

```
a = ['one']*3       // a = ['one', 'one', 'one']
b = [a]*3           // b = [['one', 'one', 'one'], ['one', 'one', 'one'], ['one', 'one', 'one']]
b[1][2] = 'two'
```

And now, b is

```
[['one', 'one', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'two']]
```

Because we made `b` refer three times the same object referred by `a`, reassigning any one of the component, change is seen at three places.

But, then why the same thing occurs when

```
a = [['one']]*3        // a = [['one'], ['one'], ['one']]
a[1] = ['two']
```

does not make `a = ['two', 'two', 'two']`, but just `[['one'], ['two'], ['one']` as if a now has three different objects pointed to.

Am I missing some logic here?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699736/why-should-i-refer-to-names-and-binding-in-python-instead-of-variables-and/20700226#20700226) relates to yours and might help understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not changing the contents of `a[1]`, you are rebinding it to point to a separate array. This has no effect on `a[0]` and `a[2]`.

Try the following instead:

```
In [4]: a = [['one']]*3

In [5]: a[1][0] = 'two'

In [6]: a
Out[6]: [['two'], ['two'], ['two']]
```

Comment: seems an acceptable answer :)... but a bit of confusion: a is a 1d array as much as b was 2d in the previous example. Then why do we need `a[1][0]` to refer to the first element of the object explicitly?... it appears as if `a` and `a[1]` are two different references here :(

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: I am not sure I follow your last remark. `a`, `a[1]` and `a[1][0]` are indeed three different references.

Comment: I was trying to understand where exactly `a` and `b` differ. It was evident that `b[0][1], b[1][1]', and `b[2][1]` referred to the same object, then why not in `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`.... perhaps I am to understand a bit more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

A key thing to remember is that objects have existence and an identity independent of names which point to them; and `x = y` does *not* mean "change the value of the object pointed to by `x` to what `y` is pointing to". It means "make `x` point to what `y` is pointing to".

Using `id` might help to clarify what is going on:

```
>>> a = [['one']]*3
>>> (id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(a[2]))
(140193404836320, 140193404836320, 140193404836320)
>>> a[1] = ['two']
>>> (id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(a[2]))
(140193404836320, 140193368088088, 140193404836320)
```

Initially, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]` are all the same object, as one would expect:

```
       +------+------+------+
  a -->|      |      |      |
       +------+------+------+
            \    |     /
             |   |     |
             v   v     v
             +---------+
             | ['one'] |
             +---------+
```

Then `a[1] = ['two']` makes `a[1]` point to a new object:

```
       +------+------+------+
  a -->|      |      |      |
       +------+------+------+
         |       |      |
         |       |      |
         |       |      |
         |       v      |
         |  +---------+ |
         |  | ['two'] | |
         |  +---------+ |
         |              |
         |  +---------+ | 
         \> | ['one'] |</
            +---------+
```

Note that the diagram is simplified to show the essentials, `['one']` and `['two']` aren't simple values as they appear in the diagram.