# Ruby: semantics of variables and assignment similar to Python's?

Tags: python, ruby, object, variable-assignment

In python, it's said that variables are not like those in C, but are really names that are bound to objects.  See, for example, ["Understanding python's name binding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228461/understanding-pythons-name-binding), ["Why should I refer to 'names' and 'binding' in Python instead of 'variables' and 'assignment'?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699736/why-should-i-refer-to-names-and-binding-in-python-instead-of-variables-and), and ["Facts and myths about Python names and values"](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

At a broad level, is this also true of Ruby?

Comment: Yes, ruby variables are references bound to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes