# Why function changes global list and not global integer with the same code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why in the first code the function update created a local variable with the same name (integ) without affecting the global integ while in the second code it changed the global value of list and didn't create a local list with the same name?

```
integ = 5
def update(integ):
    integ += 2
update(integ)
print(integ)


list = [1,10]
def update2(list):
    list += [2]
update2(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: Ultimately this is because lists are mutable. The global reference to `list` hasn't changed, its contents have. That's not a thing with numbers.

Comment: `+=` on a list (somewhat misleadingly) mutates the list. `+=` on an int only reassigns the variable.

Comment: use the keyword `global` within a function to refer to a global variable.

Comment: Try assigning to `list` rather than mutating the existing list, eg `list = list + [2]`. That behaves exactly the same as the example where you assign a new integer object to the name `integ`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/20699736/1256452

Comment: BTW, please don't shadow the built-in `list` type. It can lead to odd error messages if you later try to call `list`. And when you use it in example code like this it can make it confusing when people want to talk about your code.